# IronRouter extending data option on route controller

Tags: inheritance, meteor, iron-router

Is there a way to extend the `data` option when using IronRouter and the `RouteController`, It seems like it gets overridden when I inherit from a super controller, the child controller doesn't extend the defined `data` properties. I have had similiar issues with the `yieldTemplates` option on a route and used a workaround (underscore _extends) but it didn't work in this case:

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
     data: function(){
          return {
                 user: Meteor.user()   
         }     
   }
});

ChildController = ApplicationController.extend({
  data: function(){
        return {
               // I expect to inherit Meteor.User ?????
               someData: {}
        }
   }
});
```

EDIT:

After using `underscore` and the `extend` function to inherit the prototype function, I am still unable to inherit in `route` definition's that use the `ChildController`

```
this.route('someRoute', {
   template: 'task_template',
   //tasks is not available on the template
   data: function () {
            var base = ChildController.data.call(this);
            console.log(base);
            return _.extend(base, {
                tasks: Tasks.find({state: 'Open'})
            });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you want to do this and what you are trying to achievie? Maybe there's another way?

Comment: You need to also invoke the parent (super) controller from child's data().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use something similar to this in a production app:

```
Router.route('/test/:testparam', {
    name: 'test',
    controller: 'ChildController'
});

ParentController = RouteController.extend({
    data: function() {
        console.log('child params: ', this.params);
        return {
            foo: 'bar'
        };
    }
});

ChildController = ParentController.extend({
    data: function() {
        var data = ChildController.__super__.data.call(this);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }
});
```

Using `__super__` seems to do the trick!
You can than use _.extend to extend the data (http://underscorejs.org/#extend)

Comment: Can this be done without extending controller? by using directly on ```this.route``` definition?

Answer (score 3):

To add to the selected answer, note that if you're using Coffeescript the following will yield the same result:

```
class @ChildController extends ParentController
  data: -> super()
  # or if you want to add to it:
  data: ->
    _.extend super(), { extraThing: 'some value' }
```

Comment: Really don't know why people didn't vote 4 u. Just an awesome solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think `_.extends` should work in this case as well:

```
ChildController = ApplicationController.extend({
  data: function() {
    var base = ApplicationController.data.call(this);
    return _.extends(base, {
      someData: {},
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it `extends` or `extend`, I tried both but still unable to use data from the `ChildController`. If i remove the `data` definition from the `ApplicationController` it works

Answer (score 0):

Another option that may achieve the same result is to define a method on your parent controller, then call it using **super** without extending anything. It's slightly more work for each controller but is easier to apply retroactively. Also it makes the method optional for your child controller rather than by default.

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
        waitOn: function() {
           return [Meteor.subscribe('customUserPublish')];
        },
        GetProfileWithEmail: function(){
           var user = Meteor.user();
           var profile = user.profile;
           profile.email = user.emails[0].address;
           return profile;
        }
    });

ProfileController = ApplicationController.extend({
        waitOn: function() {
          return [Meteor.subscribe('anotherCollectionPublish')];
        },
        data: function(){
          return {
            profile:  function(){
              var profile = ApplicationController.__super__.GetProfileWithEmail.call(this);
              console.log('profile from super', profile);
              return profile;
            }
          }
        }
});
```

Remember that you have to subscribe to the published collection as well and I believe that you need to use the waitOn array option so that it will merge the subs properly (admittedly I always use an array format so YMMV). You can access the data in your template using {{#with profile}}...{{/with}} or if you were getting back an array of objects use {{#each profile}}...{{/each}}.